# The type or namespace name 'dynamic' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, visual-studio-2010

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel).

Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.5.50709 SP1Rel

I am compiling to .net framework 4.0.

Whenever I try to use the dynamic or var data types, I get the error shown in the subject line:

The type or namespace name 'dynamic' could not be found.

The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found.

I am trying to use JsonFX to parse data that I receive from another web service.  Sometimes with data will represent a "message", and sometimes it will represent a "track".  According to this [JsonFx Documentation](https://github.com/jsonfx/jsonfx%20JsonFX%20Documentation), I should be able to follow the example for "Serialize to/from dynamic types (default for .NET 4.0):"

I added a page to my site called test.  The code block below is from Test.aspx.cs 
The code I am trying to use is this:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using JsonFx;
using JsonFx.Json;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Data = "";
        Data = @"[{""meta"":{""account"":""orbitinte"",""event"":""track""},""payload"":{""id"":410827200397312213,""id_str"":""410827200397312213"",""asset"":""359551031717134"",""recorded_at"":""2013-02-07T15:59:04Z"",""received_at"":""2013-02-07T16:00:37Z"",""fields"":{}}},{""meta"":{""account"":""orbitinte"",""event"":""track""},""payload"":{""id"":410827200409895125,""id_str"":""410827200409895125"",""asset"":""359551031717134"",""recorded_at"":""2013-02-07T16:00:04Z"",""received_at"":""2013-02-07T16:00:37Z"",""fields"":{}}}]";
        Data = @"[{""meta"":{""account"":""orbitinte"",""event"":""message""},""payload"":{""id"":410865901198377173,""thread_id"":null,""parent_id"":410865891354345685,""id_str"":""410865901198377173"",""thread_id_str"":"""",""parent_id_str"":""410865891354345685"",""type"":""message"",""channel"":""com.mdi.services.adminProtocol"",""sender"":""359551031717134"",""recipient"":""@@server@@"",""asset"":""359551031717134"",""b64_payload"":""eyJlcnJvciI6ImNhbm5vdCBwYXJzZSBjb21tYW5kIn0="",""recorded_at"":""2013-02-07T18:34:25Z"",""received_at"":""2013-02-07T18:34:24Z""}}]";


        JsonReader Reader = new JsonReader();
        dynamic Output = Reader.Read(Data);

        Notifications oNotifications = new Notifications();
        oNotifications.ProcessNotifications(Data);
    }
}
```

In the web.config file:

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

I am fairly new to C# and asp.net.  But I've been searching for a solution to this problem for a while now.  Everything I see mentions the compiler version and the .net framework version.  I think I have provided all of the relevant details, but if there is anything else I should add to this question, please let me know.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any silly mistakes like missing `using` statements? This functionality should work 'out of the box'. Working at a C# shop for the last year I've never seen this problem.

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not sure.  I just modified the code block to show the using statements.

Comment: And this is inside a class or main?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your website in IIS configured to use .NET 2.0 ?  That's what it sounds like to me.  Check the configuration first.. does your test work locally ?

Your compiler should look like this:

```
<compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
```

Yours is set to Version=2.0.0.0

Comment: During runtime, Environment.Version reports 4.0.30319.18034

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, and it did not make a difference.

Comment: What is the actual error that you're getting when you go to visit the page ? In IIS, under the AppPool section (I think) did you verify that the dropdown is set to .NET 4 ?  Are you running this in VS or on IIS ?  Are you using VS or IIS express to run ?  Did you verify on the Project properties screen that you are in fact targeting .NET 4 ?

Comment: Hmmm.... This is weird.  There are no error messages when I run the page.  I did verify that the AppPool is set to 4.  I did need to change this, but it is now 4.0.  I am trying to run in VS.  My desktop machine has Windows 7 Ultimate.  When I click Help->About in IIS, it shows "Internet Information Services (Version 7.5.7600.16385).  I did verify that I am targeting .NET 4.  So it looks like the real problem is that I cannot run the project from within VS because of this error, but the site runs.  I really want to be able to debug this, so running in the IDE is necessary.

Comment: Problem solved.  In my web.config file, I was missing the targetFramework="4.0" in the system.web section.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Oh great!  I knew it had to be some sort of configuration issue.. it's odd that the settings screens were showing that when it wasn't the case.  Good luck on your project.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp` in your project.

A little more info on this DLL can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2460934/128217).

Comment: This is most likely the issue - use of the `dynamic` keyword implicitly relies on this assembly.

Comment: I did not originally have a reference to Microsoft.CSharp in my project.  I added it, and it did not help.  I also added a "using Microsoft.CSharp" to the code file, and I still get the error.

Comment: I just restarted the IDE hoping it would solve the problem, but it did not.

Comment: Problem solved.  In my web.config file, I was missing the targetFramework="4.0" in the system.web section.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @zimdanen, please understand that your advice was necessary in helping me resolve this problem.  I wish I could accept both answers, since it was a combination of both that ultimately led to the solution.